How can I close modal when I update data in vue.js?
I am new to vue.js and I try to close the modal when i update the data.
I write this for pencil:
<i class="mdi mdi-pencil"
   @click.prevent="$bvModal.show(type.title)"
></i>

This for modal:
<b-modal
  :id="type.title"
  ref="modal"
  title="Update holiday type"
  centered
  hide-footer
>
  <FormModal
    cardTitle="Update holiday type"
    description=""
    :value="type.title"
    action="update"
    @formData="parseFormData"
    :holidayTypeID="type.id"
  ></FormModal>

This is the function:
holidaysTypeUpdate(value, holidayID) {
  console.log("Modal title:", value);
  console.log("Value id: ", holidayID);
  this.$bvModal.hide(value);

  session
    .put(`api/holidays/holiday-type/${holidayID}/action/`, {
      title: value,
    })
    .then(() => {
      this.alertSchema = {
        alertVariant: "success",
        alertMsg: "Holiday updated",
        show: true,
      };
      this.fetchHolidayTypes();
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log(e.response.data);
    });
},

My problem is that when I don't change anything in data and I press update the modal closes, but when I change the data, the data is changed but modal doesn't close. How can I solve this?

Which version of vue.js you are using? Please add version specific tag and consider adding code to a snippet.

The version of vue.js I use is vue2

Does this answer your question? How can I close the vue modal when I update the data?

No, nothing of them is right

The solution is this:
<i
                              class="mdi mdi-pencil"
                              @click.prevent="$bvModal.show(`Rel${type.id}`)"
                            ></i>

<b-modal
                              :id="`Rel${type.id}`"
                              ref="modal"
                              title="Update holiday type"
                              centered
                              hide-footer
                            >
                              <FormModal
                                cardTitle="Update holiday type"
                                description=""
                                :value="type.title"
                                action="update"
                                @formData="parseFormData"
                                :holidayTypeID="type.id"
                              ></FormModal>
                            </b-modal>

holidaysTypeUpdate(value, holidayID) {    
  session
    .put(`api/holidays/holiday-type/${holidayID}/action/`, {
      title: value,
    })
    .then(() => {
      this.alertSchema = {
        alertVariant: "success",
        alertMsg: "Holiday updated",
        show: true,
      };
      this.fetchHolidayTypes();
      this.$bvModal.hide(`Rel${holidayID}`);

      setTimeout(() => {
          this.alertSchema.show = false;
        }, 2000);
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log(e.response.data);
    });
},

